# Como copio los datos de un input type=date en otro input?

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

Tengo un input tipo date donde introduzco una fecha pero necesito copiarla en otro input tipo hidden en tiempo real, me imagino que JS tiene esa facilidad y que si no ingresa los datos en el primer input lance un alert o algo parecido señalando que el campo está vacío

acá están los dos input

```
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha">

            <input type="hidden" name="fechaAporte">
```

Comment: e intentaste algo? si, con js lo podes hacer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir un `eventListener` de tipo `change` a al input que deseas analizar, luego cada vez que se detecte un cambio en la función del `eventListener` puedes captar el valor con el que se cambió y ese mismo valor asignarlo a tu otro input, un ejemplo de eso sería lo siguiente:

```js
const hiddenInput = document.querySelector('#hidden');

document.querySelector('#date')
    .addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        hiddenInput.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(hiddenInput.value);
    });
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" />

<input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="fechaAporte" />
```

Comment: Gracias man, era la respuesta me funcionó. Y cómo haría para mandar un Alert en dado caso de que el input tipo hidden esté vacío?

Comment: Pregunta y si quiero que se respete el formato de dia mes y año ?? como se le haria